# Is std::set `erase ( const key_type& x )` implemented in STL same way ` erase ( collection.find( x ) );` does?

Tags: c++, stl, set

Is std::set `erase ( x )` implemented in STL same way `erase ( collection.find( x ) );` (where `x` is `const   key_type&`) does?

Comment: Have a look at your STL implemention, and let us know what you find!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure they're likely to be quite similar, but they'll have differences because one must handle an 'unfound' element in a certain way and the other doesn't need to worry about that (and likely doesn't in a non-debug build).

- `std::set::erase( const key_type& )` will return `0` or `1` depending on if a matching element to erase is found.
- `std::set::erase( iterator )` returns nothing and has defined behavior only if the iterator passed in is dereferenceable. So if you pass in `find(x)` where `x` isn't in the set, you have a problem.